# Does disabling NCQ cause any bad effects on the computer?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, sata

A few months ago, I started seeing these errors on my computer:

```
[39441.061910] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[39441.061917] ata3.01: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0xe SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
```

What I did was replace the old SATA cables with new ones and the errors stopped popping up.

However today the exact same error messages were shown when my computer crashed while I was doing something important. I was able to see these errors when I switched to tty1.

Now I'm pretty sure, that it isn't my cable's fault as it is only 2-3 weeks old. What I did was to disable NCQ by typing:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="libata.force=noncq
```

in my `/etc/default/grub` file and *BOY* it worked like a charm. However, I'm a little bit concerned that it might have a bad effect on my computer because Wikipedia states NCQ like this:

```
This(NCQ) can reduce the amount of unnecessary drive head movement, resulting in increased performance (and slightly decreased wear of the drive) for workloads where multiple simultaneous read/write requests are outstanding, most often occurring in server-type applications.
```

**Will disabling NCQ have a bad effect on my computer overall?**

Answer (score 0):

It has a major impact on random access, small-block read/write performance (because the SSD cannot issue the read/write operations in parallel internally).